# Python: remove quotes from field retrieved from DB

Tags: python, quotes

I am with Python, and I am making a query to a MySQL database:

```
lists = db.execute("SELECT list, item, created_at FROM lists WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC", user_id=session["user_id"])
```

«Item» is a text field where I store an array of strings.
The result of this query is:

```
[{'list': '1', 'item': '["a", "b"]', 'created_at': '2020-07-12 16:59:21'}]
```

As you can see `item` value is quoted. How can I unquote it? I can not use a JSON field as I'm in MySQL 3.22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the `str` back to a `list`

  - `'["a", "b"]'` is a `str`, `literal_eval` will convert it back to a `list`, `['a', 'b']`.
- Iterate through the list, and update the `'item'` value in each dictionary.

  - Address the correct list index using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```py
from ast import literal_eval

for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    lists[i]['item'] = literal_eval(l['item'])

prints(lists)
[{'list': '1', 'item': ['a', 'b'], 'created_at': '2020-07-12 16:59:21'}]
```

### Using [`.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) instead of `enumerate`

```py
for l in lists:
    l.update(item=literal_eval(l.get('item')))
```